# Combine function flatpickr with WP plugin code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, datepicker, flatpickr

I have a wordpress plugin that uses flatpickr calendar. The code in this plugin differs from flatpickr examples. Here is the part of the code where it is used:

```
<script>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                'use strict';

                var cpoCfg;
                if (typeof window.UniCpo !== 'undefined') {
                    cpoCfg = window.UniCpo;
                } else if (typeof window.UniCpoCart !== 'undefined') {
                    cpoCfg = window.UniCpoCart;
                }

                var fpCfg = {
                    locale: cpoCfg.flatpickrCfg.locale,
                };

                <?php if ( $is_datepicker_disabled && $is_timepicker ) { ?>
                    fpCfg.enableTime = true;
                    fpCfg.noCalendar = true;
                    fpCfg.minTime = "<?php echo esc_html( $time_min ) ?>";
                    fpCfg.maxTime = "<?php echo esc_html( $time_max ) ?>";
                    fpCfg.minuteIncrement = "<?php echo esc_html( $minute_step ) ?>";
                    <?php if ( $time_24hr ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.time_24hr = true;
                        fpCfg.dateFormat = "H:i";
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        fpCfg.dateFormat = "h:i K";
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php if ( 'range' === $picker_type ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.mode          = 'range';
                        var defaultValue    = '<?php echo esc_attr( $default_value ); ?>'.split(' - ');
                        if (defaultValue[0].length > 0 && typeof defaultValue[1] !== 'undefined'
                            && defaultValue[1].length > 0 && moment(defaultValue[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()
                            && moment(defaultValue[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()) {
                            fpCfg.defaultDate = defaultValue;
                        }
                    <?php } elseif ( 'single' === $picker_type  ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.defaultDate = '<?php echo esc_html( $default_value ); ?>';
                    <?php } elseif ( 'multiple' === $picker_type  ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.mode = 'multiple';
                        var defaultValue    = '<?php echo esc_attr( $default_value ); ?>'.split(' - ');
                        if (defaultValue[0].length > 0 && typeof defaultValue[1] !== 'undefined'
                            && defaultValue[1].length > 0 && moment(defaultValue[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()
                            && moment(defaultValue[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()) {
                            fpCfg.defaultDate = defaultValue;
                        }
                        fpCfg.conjunction = "<?php echo $conjunction; ?>";
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( $is_timepicker ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.enableTime = true;
                        fpCfg.minTime = "<?php echo esc_html( $time_min ) ?>";
                        fpCfg.maxTime = "<?php echo esc_html( $time_max ) ?>";
                        fpCfg.minuteIncrement = "<?php echo esc_html( $minute_step ) ?>";
                        <?php if ( $time_24hr ) { ?>
                            fpCfg.time_24hr = true;
                            fpCfg.dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i";
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            fpCfg.dateFormat = "Y-m-d h:i K";
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( false !== strpos( $date_min, 'moment' ) || false !== strpos( $date_min, 'Date' ) ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.minDate = <?php echo esc_html( $date_min ) ?>;
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        fpCfg.minDate = '<?php echo esc_html( $date_min ) ?>';
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ( false !== strpos( $date_max, 'moment' ) || false !== strpos( $date_max, 'Date' ) ) { ?>
                        fpCfg.maxDate = <?php echo esc_html( $date_max ) ?>;
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        fpCfg.maxDate = '<?php echo esc_html( $date_max ) ?>';
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ! empty( $disabled_dates ) ) { ?>
                        var disabled    = '<?php echo esc_html( $disabled_dates ) ?>';
                        var disabledArr = disabled.split(', ');
                        fpCfg.disable   = disabledArr;
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>

                jQuery('#<?php echo esc_attr( $slug ) ?>-field').flatpickr(fpCfg);

            });
        </script>
```

I need to insert this function in this code to disable weekends:

```
 disableFunction: {
        locale: {
            firstDayOfWeek: 1
        },
        disable: [
            function(date) {
                // return true to disable

                return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

            }
        ]
    },
```

Information from [here](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-dates-by-a-function)

Please help me how to combine it?

I tried changing the variables but it didn't work.

Comment: You should be able to add that directly inside the `var fpCfg = {...}` initialization.

Comment: I added this part to the existing one 'var fpCfg = {'
Does not work
`var fpCfg = {
locale: window.UniCpo.flatpickrCfg.locale,
disableFunction: {
locale: {
firstDayOfWeek: 0
},
disable: [
function(date) {
return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
}
]
},`

Comment: Where did you actually get `disableFunction` from? That does not appear to be the syntax the documentation suggests, https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-dates-by-a-function